# Laravel Eloquent attribute casting doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, casting, decimal

I have a field in my database that stores a `decimal` value. It's defined in my database migration as such:

```
$table->decimal('buy_amount', 16, 8)->default(0);
```

Now reading from the database using Laravel Eloquent it returns a string value instead. [According to the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting), I tried casting it in the model file using the `$casts` array however it makes **no difference**. It's worth mentioning that every other cast works fine except for decimals.

```
protected $casts = [
    'buy_amount' => 'decimal:8',
];
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Store price as [int](https://twitter.com/rasmus/status/921520204365971456).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because PHP doesn't have a `decimal` type, so the value is converted to a `string` (see [this Laracasts post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-eloquent-returns-string-for-decimal))

When casting to a decimal, the `asDecimal(...)` function in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes` is called; this function uses the native PHP function `number_format`, [which returns a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).